# C++11 std::function and std::reference wrapper used for sorting std::set

Tags: c++, c++11, std, functor, std-function

I have a C++ class, and one of its fields is a std::set of objects. I want to write my own comparison function, or let the user specify one. In C++11 there's a new way to handle generic function types: std::function. It works with function pointers, member function pointers, lambda functions, etc.

I tried to write a simple experiment program but it keeps craching all the time, even when I do what the C++11 Wikipedia article suggets. Maybe I just don't get how std::function and std::ref are supposed to be used.

Anyway, the point is that when I created a std::function from a simple lambda function and made it a class member, the sizeof of the class grew by 22. When I created a std::function from a pointer to a global function, this std::function's sizeof was 32. So the size is big. I'm going to have many objects using the same comparison function, so I prefer to have one function used by all of them.

I have two ideas, tell me what you think. One idea, use std::ref to store a reference to a function, this way I can define one function and many objects will use it to compare the std::set elements. Second idea: if it doesn't work like that, or the resulting function object is too big anyway, maybe I can use a shared_ptr.

You may wonder: why not have one static std::function member? The answer: because then ALL objects will use the same comparison function. I want to be able to have, for example, 1000 objects, with 400 using one comparison function and 600 using a different comparison function.

Example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
private:
     std::function<bool (int, int)> compare;
     std::set<int> set;
};
```

Now how do I make the std::set use the std::function, and have many MyClass objects use the same function?

I'd like to be able to change the comparison function during run-time, so that the user would be able to choose the ordering of the objects in the set (which are displayed by GUI).

Comment: Instead of describing what you do or want to do textually, why not make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and show us the actual code?

Comment: Because I never heard of anything called SSCCE and because I don't have the actual code; I posted the question because I was looking for guidance for how to write it properly. (And I got guidance, see answers below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to represent shared ownership is using `std::shared_ptr`.  That adds a bit more overhead, forcing you to allocate the `std::function` on the heap, but a `shared_ptr` is smaller than a `std::function` and it will correctly manage its lifetime so while any objects are still using the function object it will be kept alive and will automatically be destroyed when no longer needed.

As you suggest, a `reference_wrapper` referring to the shared function can be used as the `set`'s comparison object, because a `reference_wrapper` is callable if it wraps a callable type.

```
class MyClass
{
     typedef std::function<bool (int, int)> func_type;
public:
     MyClass(std::shared_ptr<func_type> const& f)
     : compare(f), set( std::ref(*f) )
     { }
private:
     std::shared_ptr<func_type> compare;
     std::set<int, std::reference_wrapper<func_type>> set;
};
```

A `reference_wrapper` cannot be null (like a reference) so you must construct the `std::set` with a valid `reference_wrapper` object.

Since the `std::reference_wrapper` in the `std::set` just holds a non-owning pointer to the `std::function`, you need to be careful to update the set's comparison object at the same time as updating the `shared_ptr`, or you could drop the last reference to the function, so the `shared_ptr` would destroy it, leaving a dangling pointer in the set. That could be done like this:

```
void MyClass::replace_cmp(std::shared_ptr<func_type> const& f)
{
  set = std::set<int, std::reference_wrapper<func_type>>( std::ref(*f) );
  compare = f;
}
```

Comment: But now, how do I pass it to the std::set? The set needs a callable type, so I'll need to write a class with operator() which calls "compare". Right? or there's a shorter way?

Comment: sorry, I missed that bit :) answer updated - a `reference_wrapper` provides `operator()`

Comment: So the reference_wrapper just calls the std::function pointed by the shared_ptr it stores? And a question about performance: if the std::set takes an object with operator(), and constructs an object from it using the default ctor, will it usually be smart and try to inline the function? (since it's known at compilation time in this case) In my case the function is not known so I lose any chance of that

Comment: The `std::reference_wrapper` stores a (non-owning) pointer to the `std::function`, which is owned by the `shared_ptr`. Invoking `operator()` on the `reference_wrapper` forwards the call to the `function`. You're correct that a `std::set` would often be able to inline the comparisons, but `std::function` will usually prevent such inlining.

Comment: Is there a faster way I could use? I mean, implement the same idea not using the std::function solution? Maybe there's a better/faster solution I missed

Comment: Not if you want to be able to change the set's ordering. Inlining the comparisons is easy for the compiler when the set's comparison function is part of its type, and cannot change, e.g. `std::set<int, MyCmp>`, but if you want to be able to replace the comparison you need an indirection, either a function pointer or `std::function` or similar, and it's much harder for compilers to inline indirect calls. I doubt you'll notice a performance problem, a good implementation of `std::function` is still pretty quick.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use std::function like you described :)

Answer (score 2):

You tell the set to use your comparison function in your [constructor initializer list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html):

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    template<typename Fc>
    MyClass(Fc compare_func)
        : compare(compare_func),  // Initialize the comparison function
          set(compare)            // Tell the set to use out function for comparison
        {}
};
```